# Interpreting Kruskal for cosmological spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I'm dealing with a metric of the form:
$$ds^2 = -f(r)dt^2 + a(t)(1/f(r)dr^2 + a(t)r^2d\Omega^2)$$

Where $f$ is just $f = 1 - 2m/r$. The first thing I did was to introduce a conformal time coordinate $\eta$ such that 
$$d\eta = \frac{dt}{\sqrt{a(t)}}$$

This conformal transformation maps the region $t:(0,\infty)$ to $\eta: (0, P)$ where $P$ is just a number. Basically, I applied a technique used in dealing with RW metrics when one wants to obtain a compact picture of the spacetime. In the case of the metric defined above, the conformal transformation converts it into a "Schwarzschild-looking" metric times a conformal factor.

$g_{\mu\nu} = \omega(\eta)^{2}g^{'}_{\mu\nu}$

where $g^{'}_{\mu\nu} = -f(r)d\eta^2 + (1/f(r)dr^2 + r^2d\Omega^2 $
I converted this to Kruskal coordinates. Like the usual, lines of constant r are hyperbolas and lines of constant $\eta$ and thus constant t are straight lines with slope $\tanh(\frac{\eta}{4m})$.

Here comes my problem, in normal Schwarzschild, the line $t=\infty$ and $r=2m$ are both represented by the line T=X, where T and X are the kruskal coordinates. However, in this case because of the conformal mapping, the line $t=\infty$ which is equivalent to $\eta = P/4m$ has slope

$\tanh(\frac{P}{4m})<1$ when $r>2m$ because of constraints I placed on $a(t)$ (remember that the definition of $\eta$ depends on $a(t)$). So the line $t=\infty$ is always below the line T=X (which is also the surface $r=2m$. Does this mean to say that particles outside r=2m can never reach the surface r=2m?

Comment: hi, what is a(t) ? what are RW metrics? Please provide formulas and/or references

Comment: RW metrics are robertson walker metrics. My question basically is, if i have a metric which when transformed to kruskal coordinates gives lines of constant t that all lie below the line T=X (which represent r=2m) including the line t= infinity, does that mean to say that r=2m is unreachable? If it helps, i calculated the curvature quantities and the curvature scalars imply non-coordinate singularities at r=0 and r=2m. So either r=2m is unreachable and that is due to it being a singularity, or this particular spacetime is not well behaved in kruskal coordinates